# How do I specify an HTML5 Doctype format in Scalate for Scaml?

Tags: scala, scalate, scalatra

I'm using Scalatra's built-in Scalate support but I want my default.scaml layout to render an HTML5 Doctype. The Scalate documentation states [*When the format option is set to :html5, !!! is always <!DOCTYPE html>*](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scaml-reference.html#Doctype%3a__code_____format__code_) but I can't find anyone saying exactly how to set the format option.

TIA!

Comment: I just watched a video in which James Strachan recommended Jade over Scaml in almost any situation.

Comment: On the Jade GitHub page, under implementations, it lists Scala, which links to Scaml. So is Scaml the Scala impl of Jade, or what's the difference?

Comment: I guess they're simply linking it wrong. Here's the Scalate/Jade link:
http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
!!! 5
```

See the [user guide](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scaml-reference.html#Doctype:__code_____format__code_) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks James, I read the XHTML5 and skipped right over it. I didn't realize till I reread it that they're using the same doctype.

Answer (score 2):

Also for reference, it looks like if you want to change the default `!!!` declaration to HTML5, you can change the ScamlOptions.format var. [Seems there are other helpful options in there also.](http://scalate.fusesource.org/maven/1.3/scalate-core/scaladocs/org/fusesource/scalate/scaml/ScamlOptions%24.html)

```
import org.fusesource.scalate.scaml.ScamlOptions

class MyScalatraFilter extends ScalatraFilter with ScalateSupport {
    ScamlOptions.format = ScamlOptions.Format.html5
    ...
}
```